# Clean topology with holes in a mesh with bevel modifier?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, topology, bevel

So this question today is not just how to make a hole, but I'd like to know what's the correct way of making a number of holes on a mesh having a clean topology.

I have seen numerous tutorials with lots of methods how to make a hole, and the topology result is nice and clean but it's demonstrated on a single cube. (I know if I add a subdivision modifier ill get better looking circular holes on my mesh).

But for this purpose I added a bevel modifier so the edges on these models are more natural and smooth. One problem I'm getting is, when I make holes in the mesh, the bevel seems to be affected. The edges become less smooth and become sharp. And on some of the mesh in the example, depending on the method I use, the mesh looks unclean, the holes need more loop cuts to clean up. In order to preserve the bevel on one model in the example, I added the bevel modifier and then stared making holes on the mesh so I can keep the smooth edges.

So what method would be appropriate to have smooth edges on a model, but also be able to make holes which would leave a cleaner topology.

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my way of making holes. It's probably not the best one, but looks good enough for me.

1) We subdivide a plane one time to many, and select 4 quads for each hole.

[image: Subdivided plane]

2) We do inset. (<kbd>I</kbd>)

[image: Inset]

3) We use `Mesh: LoopTools` add-on (just enable it) using `Cicrcle` tool.

(in edit mode right click and then `LoopTools`->`Circle`)

[image: Circle]

4) Inset one more time. (<kbd>I</kbd>)

[image: Inset Twice]

5) Extrude downwards. (<kbd>E</kbd>)

[image: Extruded]

6) Add Subdivision Surface modifier

[image: subdivided]

7) Smooth shading (subdivided 2 times)

[image: Smooth shading]

8) Render Eevee

[image: Eevee]

To make hole sharper you can make more insets, and extrude down several times to put loop-cuts in all holes.

[image: Insets]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an add-on in step 3 of @Filip Franik's answer then enable vertex snapping, move the 3d cursor to the centre point, change the Transform Pivot Point to 3D Cursor, select the four vertices and scale down. It's more of an approximation but you can always adjust until it looks good.

Comment: The whole question was about a workflow that allows making many holes at the same time. For a single hole all you need to use is Shift+Alt+S to start "To Sphere" tool. It will allow you to change the 2D square to a 2D circle without touching the 3D Cursor. (This is also a very good tool to change a subdivided cube into a sphere for better topology!) https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/to_sphere.html

Comment: I had no idea about that shortcut, thanks!